# using sed to turn paragraph to lines

Tags: unix, sed

Using sed and any basic commands, I'm trying to count the number of words in each separate passage that has many separate passages. Each passage begins with a specific number and increases. Example:

0:1.1 This is the first passage...

0:1.2 This is the second passage...

The difficult thing is that each passage is a paragraph that is word wrapped and not a single line. I could count the words in each passage if they were on single lines. How can I do this?Thanks for the help

I did figure how to count each passage with:

grep '[0-9]:[0-9]' file | wc -l

Comment: "Word-wrap" means displaying a long line as multiple lines that fit into the window width, i.e. the line is not actually broken but just displayed so. Do you mean to say each passage is actually broken into multiple lines?

Comment: Is there a blank line between each passage?

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` solution might work for you:

```
awk '/^[0-9]:[0-9]\.[0-9]/{ 
       if (pass_num) printf "%s, word count: %i\n", pass_num, word_count
       pass_num=$1
       word_count=-1
     }
     { word_count+=NF }
     END { printf "%s, word count: %i\n", pass_num, word_count }
    ' file
```

Test input:

```
# cat file
0:1.1 I am le passage one.
There are many words in me.

0:1.2 I am le passage two.
One two three four five six
Seven

0:1.3 I am "Hello world"
```

Test output:

```
0:1.1, word count: 11
0:1.2, word count: 12
0:1.3, word count: 4
```

---

How it works:

Each word is separated by empty space, so each word can be represented by each field in `awk`, i.e. word count in a line is equal to `NF`. The word count is summed up every line until the next passage.

When it encounters a new passage (indicated by the presence of a passage number), it

- prints out the previous passage's number and word count.
- set passage number to this new passage number
- reset passage word count (`-1` because we don't want the passage number be counted)

The `END{..}` block is needed because the final passage doesn't have a trigger that causes it to print out the passage number and word count.

The `if (pass_num)` is to suppress `printf` when `awk` encounters the first passage.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$bb;N;/\n[0-9]+:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/!s/\n/ /g;ta;:b;h;s/\n.*//;s/([0-9]+:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1 = $(wc -w <<<"\2")"/ep;g;D' file
```

It forms each section into a single line then counts the words in the section less the section number (newlines are replaced by spaces).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
0:1.1 This is the first passage...
welcome to the SO, you leart a lot of things here.

0:1.2 This is the second passage...
wer qwerqrq            ewqr e
0:1.3 This is the second passage...
```

Using sed and GNU grep:

```
$ sed -n '/0:1.1/,/[0-9]:[0-9]\.[0-9]/{//!p}' file | grep -Eo '[[:alpha:]]*'   | wc -l
11
```

0:1.1 -> Give the passage number here in which you want to count.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]+:[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+' -v FS='[ \t\n]+' 'NF > 0 { print R ": " NF - 2 } { R = RT }'
```

If it is run on the file listed by *doubledown*, the output is:

```
0:1.1: 11
0:1.2: 12
0:1.3: 4
```

#### Explanation

This works by splitting the input into records according to `[0-9]+:[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+` and splitting into fields at whitespace. The record separator is off by one, hence the `{R = RT }`, the field counter is off by two because each record starts and ends with an `FS`, hence the `NF - 2`.

#### Edit - only count fields containing `[:alnum:]`

The above also counts e.g. ellipsis (...) as words, to avoid this do something like this:

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]+:[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+' -v FS='[ \t\n]+' '
  NF > 0 { 
    wc = NF-2
    for(i=2; i<NF; i++)
      if($i !~ /[[:alnum:]]+/)
        wc--
    print R ": " wc
  } 
  { R = RT }'
```